# Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.2'

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ckan

I was trying to install ckan following the [installation  guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) on a ubuntu 14.04

And running the:

```
pip install -r /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/requirements.txt
```

had this error:

```
    Downloading/unpacking psycopg2==2.4.5 (from -r /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/requirements.txt (line 33))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz (719kB): 719kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

    Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.2'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
```

I tryed running with psql 10 and with psql 9.5 both, and it fails...

I've done a little bit of resarch and in some pages is said that is psycopg2 bug but I'm not sure..

any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use Postgresql 10+ with CKAN you need [PR 3978](this PR: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3978) which is currently only on CKAN's  master branch - not on the latest release (2.7.2).

I suggest that for the time being you stick with Postgres 9.5 that is the default for Ubuntu 14.04/16.04, which are the choices currently supported by the CKAN team.

You also mention the problem persists with Postgres 9.5 installed. You'll need to uninstall 10.2 first, so please check you've done that and paste the error message in your question (in addition the the existing one) - up to the error is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I could solve the problem going through this https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3978

I just changed the version of psycopg2 and it worked with postgres 9.5 

I don't know exactly why but it worked

Comment: Good, I think. There's the chance you may suffer at some point from not taking the other bit from that PR - the register_default_json line.